# Convert Dataframe back to RDD of case class in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a dataframe of multiple case classes to an rdd of these multiple cases classes. I cant find any solution. This `wrappedArray` has drived me crazy :P

For example, assuming I am having the following:

```
case class randomClass(a:String,b: Double)
case class randomClass2(a:String,b: Seq[randomClass])
case class randomClass3(a:String,b:String)

val anRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(
 (randomClass2("a",Seq(randomClass("a1",1.1),randomClass("a2",1.1))),randomClass3("aa","aaa")),
 (randomClass2("b",Seq(randomClass("b1",1.2),randomClass("b2",1.2))),randomClass3("bb","bbb")),
 (randomClass2("c",Seq(randomClass("c1",3.2),randomClass("c2",1.2))),randomClass3("cc","Ccc"))))

val aDF = anRDD.toDF()
```

Assuming that I am having the `aDF` how can I get the `anRDD`???

I tried something like this just to get the second column but it was giving an error:

```
aDF.map { case r:Row => r.getAs[randomClass3]("_2")}
```

Comment: Could you post the error that you were given?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert indirectly using `Dataset[randomClass3]`:

```
aDF.select($"_2.*").as[randomClass3].rdd
```

Spark `DatataFrame` / `Dataset[Row]` represents data as the `Row` objects using mapping described in [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) Any call to `getAs` should use this mapping.

For the second column, which is `struct<a: string, b: string>`, it would be a `Row` as well:

```
aDF.rdd.map { _.getAs[Row]("_2") }
```

As commented by [Tzach Zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5344058/tzach-zohar) to get back a full RDD you'll need:

```
aDF.as[(randomClass2, randomClass3)].rdd
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the scala API but have you considered the [rdd value](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])?

Maybe something like :

```
aDR.rdd.map { case r:Row => r.getAs[randomClass3]("_2")}
```

Comment: `Dataframe.map(f)` actually just calls `this.rdd.map(f)` so this is identical to what the OP has tried, which doesn't work.

Comment: At least in pyspark, `df.map` no longer aliases to `df.rdd.map` as of Spark 2.0